# How to change the stroke colour of different parts of an object in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I've made an object using the pen tool in Adobe Illustrator and I want to change the stroke colour in such a way that 25% of the stroke is of the colour: #4885ed, 25% is of the colour: #3cba54; 25% is of the colour: #f4c20d, and the rest is of the colour: #db3236.
Is there a way to do this?
The object:

[image]

Comment: I'm using Adobe Illustrator CC.

Comment: WHat have you tried so far? Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52602749/edit) and post your code? If you are not looking for a way to do this programatically, then this question is off-topic for S.O. and you would have better luck getting an answer on the [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not using Illustrator for this. I'm using `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` like this:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 588 624" >
<style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[
        #india{fill:none;stroke-dasharray:641.415 1924.245;stroke-width:5px;}
        ]]> 
  </style>
<defs>
<path id="india" d="M44.688,306.845c-2.642-0.827-5.247-1.812-7.934-2.449
 c-7.525-1.783-12.961-6.64-17.922-12.115c-3.99-4.403-4.53-9.512-2.026-14.854c2.306-4.919,6.242-6.531,11.686-6.766
 c6.596-0.284,13.111-2.091,19.709-2.779c5.779-0.603,11.641-0.392,17.434-0.905c2.243-0.199,5.552-0.836,6.274-2.306
 c0.762-1.551-0.513-4.631-1.713-6.526c-4.985-7.873-10.5-15.416-15.369-23.356c-2.582-4.211-6.588-8.315-3.986-14.157
 c3.672-8.243,8.005-16.219,17.474-18.493c4.032-0.968,9.065-0.349,12.936,1.256c4.737,1.964,8.982,2.183,12.689-0.724
 c7.431-5.826,15.067-11.617,21.459-18.499c18.653-20.084,34.177-42.566,48.346-65.989c0.772-1.276,1.525-2.608,2-4.012
 c1.42-4.197-1.634-9.552-6.568-9.473c-5.098,0.081-10.358-0.507-15.294-1.78c-9.525-2.458-16.651-12.229-16.92-21.806
 c-0.135-4.806,1.695-8.259,5.759-10.819c5.485-3.455,6.007-9.796,1.154-14.155c-3.589-3.226-7.519-6.071-11.12-9.283
 c-2.096-1.87-4.059-3.974-5.711-6.242c-6.372-8.748-5.044-17.89,3.407-24.616c18.528-14.747,52.229-12.496,67.749,5.29
 c10.451,11.978,19.371,12.697,32.961,5.055c5.181-2.913,10.601-5.612,16.22-7.479c7.032-2.336,12.668,1.186,17.239,6.271
 c4.494,5,6.606,10.748,4.038,17.478c-3.285,8.608-6.82,16.937-14.894,22.513c-3.8,2.625-4.026,8.368-1.061,12.65
 c1.407,2.031,3.271,3.761,5.018,5.539c5.182,5.276,7.646,11.601,7.435,18.972c-0.176,6.16-2.896,9.354-8.999,9.768
 c-4.456,0.302-8.995,0.254-13.428-0.248c-4.95-0.561-5.789,2.074-5.396,5.899c0.938,9.138,4.561,16.785,13.183,20.993
 c8.138,3.972,13.685,10.418,18.344,17.854c4.697,7.497,6.173,15.042,0.349,22.744c-0.888,1.174-1.467,2.618-2.018,4.005
 c-2.675,6.735-2.124,9.976,4.428,13.158c11.936,5.798,24.045,11.412,36.515,15.9c31.174,11.219,62.996,20.327,95.454,27.1
 c7.458,1.557,10.065-0.686,9.464-8.257c-0.381-4.808-1.225-9.578-1.838-14.367c-0.826-6.456,1.912-10.525,7.25-10.812
 c5.214-0.28,8.339,3.143,8.534,9.35c0.307,9.727,1.146,10.837,10.825,12.763c14.199,2.825,28.383,5.9,43.038,3.948
 c5.068-0.675,8.714-3.038,10.441-7.972c0.83-2.368,0.566-3.922-2.36-4.86c-7.151-2.295-7.885-6.348-2.488-11.371
 c16.909-15.742,35.395-29.299,55.974-39.831c4.674-2.392,9.838-4.258,14.99-5.198c11.271-2.059,17.596,4.958,15.109,16.187
 c-0.739,3.339-1.827,6.602-2.325,10.473c3.985-6.749,10.243-7.52,16.81-7.148c6.936,0.392,10.565,6.872,6.53,12.62
 c-3.886,5.536-8.651,10.566-13.595,15.22c-7.027,6.616-14.689,12.554-21.815,19.071c-1.911,1.748-3.451,4.384-4.148,6.894
 c-3.555,12.812-6.272,25.877-10.297,38.531c-2.656,8.354-6.46,16.534-16.358,19.402c-1.242,0.36-2.123,3.41-2.425,5.332
 c-1.729,10.997-3.026,22.064-4.924,33.03c-0.654,3.782-1.609,8.741-6.426,9.072c-4.69,0.322-5.494-4.627-7.1-7.964
 c-1.657-3.444-3.028-7.025-4.541-10.54c-1.817-4.225-4.796-6.331-9.506-5.002c-4.005,1.13-7.466,0.017-9.815-3.157
 c-3.326-4.494-6.88-9.039-9.045-14.112c-2.422-5.675-0.439-9.354,5.03-12.401c3.338-1.859,6.749-3.614,10.238-5.166
 c4.225-1.879,7.186-8.311,4.703-12.138c-1.012-1.559-4.046-2.355-6.229-2.509c-9.259-0.653-18.662-0.158-27.786-1.56
 c-10.08-1.549-12.995-5.76-13.791-14.933c-2.819-0.678-5.428-0.978-7.758-1.946c-3.211-1.335-6.172-3.258-9.314-4.774
 c-3.105-1.5-5.582-0.384-7.182,2.446c-1.568,2.774-0.23,4.887,2.246,6.189c2.18,1.146,4.827,1.534,6.787,2.932
 c2.116,1.509,4.573,3.565,5.166,5.832c0.411,1.571-1.626,4.534-3.356,5.782c-7.349,5.303-7.827,7.007-3.646,15.167
 c7.106,13.874,9.854,28.934,11.302,44.236c1.362,14.409,0.427,15.246-13.978,16.188c-9.354,0.612-17.791,3.848-23.938,10.922
 c-24.502,28.201-53.179,51.811-82.092,75.146c-14.773,11.924-29.962,23.335-45.055,34.858c-7.585,5.792-11.407,13.24-11.051,22.807
 c1.154,31.017-3.308,61.434-9.899,91.609c-0.444,2.033-1.297,4.304-2.697,5.75c-9.604,9.928-18.997,20.12-29.249,29.348
 c-12.313,11.082-30.903,7.563-38.812-7.06c-29.107-53.818-52.476-109.855-64.615-170.123c-5.378-26.701-8.153-53.634-6.554-80.918
 c0.44-7.51-1.062-8.34-8.355-6.574c-7.409,1.794-14.955,3.111-22.502,4.226c-7.43,1.098-13.713-1.785-19.109-6.761
 c-8.327-7.679-14.723-16.752-18.977-27.236c-3.496-8.616-2.476-10.235,6.58-11.689c1.636-0.263,3.285-0.45,4.928-0.673
 C44.617,307.438,44.652,307.142,44.688,306.845z "/>
  </defs>
  
  <use xlink:href ="#india" stroke="#4885ed"  />
  <use xlink:href ="#india" stroke="#3cba54" stroke-dashoffset="641.415" />
  <use xlink:href ="#india" stroke="#f4c20d" stroke-dashoffset="1282.83" />
  <use xlink:href ="#india" stroke="#db3236" stroke-dashoffset="1924.245" />
</svg>
```

I hope its this what you need.

Comment: Thanks but the western part, i.e., Gujarat is a bit messed up. Can you give me the svg file so that I can print it using Microsoft Word?

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. I've updated the code and now the styles are inside the SVG element. So you can copy the SVG into an .svg document and you can open it on Illustrator. However there may be a problem. I've calculated the values for `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` in base of the length of the path. If you change path, you may change it's length, and this may ruin everything. It should have been better to have your SVG to begin with instead of an image.

Comment: And there is an other problem: I don't have the Adobe Illustrator CC. But older versions of illustrator are unable to understand `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset`

Comment: I pasted the code in Notepad and saved it as Map.svg. But when I opened it in Chrome, it says: This page contains the following errors: <br> error on line 46 at column 47: Namespace prefix xlink for href on use is not defined <br> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error. <br> #india{fill:none;stroke-dasharray:641.415 1924.245;stroke-width:5px;}

Comment: In my comment, by using "<br>", I mean line break (as pressing Enter posts the comment)

Comment: It opened perfectly fine in Adobe Illustrator.